# Getting 401 Unauthorized after a preflight OPTION call

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors, okta

I have an angular4 app that talks to a Web API project on a different domain. The API calls work fine if I don't add [Authorize] attribute to the APIs.

But once I add [Authorize] attribute, and correspondingly, when I implement ability to intercept all API calls in Angular4 and add Okta Bearer Authorization header token, I notice that the preflight OPTION call takes place and return 200 OK. And immediately after, it makes the GET API call but that one returns 401. I have attached the headers in the image.

Comment: Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8f9e.png

Comment: Are you saying that once you include an `Authorization` header, your calls are no longer working? If you remove it, they work? If so, why don't you just remove the header for those API calls?

Comment: I need the APIs to be authorized. And no, if I don't pass authorization, it doesn't work at all. Which is expected. My guess is something to do with CORS but I am not completely sure. I have verified my CORS settings are correct and working (when I don't have auth enabled)

Comment: @J.Doe It sounds to me like the `Authorization` header is being attached to the OPTIONS request, but not the subsequent GET request. Can you check your network console and look at the header details of each request to verify?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an allowed origin policy in your token validation. I'm not familiar with Okta as a token server but had a search in the site and found [this](https://support.okta.com/help/Documentation/Knowledge_Article/Configuration_Guides/50360933-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing), See if it helps.